# jQuery - Trigger() once every click

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-selectors

I've ran into a problem with something quite simple. When I click `#mybutton` I want to trigger a click on another button.

```
$('#mybutton').click(function(){

   $('#otherbutton').trigger('click');

});
```

When I first click `#mybutton` the `#otherbutton` will trigger once. When I click `#mybutton` the second time the `#otherbutton` will trigger twice. When I click `#mybutton` the third time the `#otherbutton` will trigger three times...and so on.

How can I stop this so that `#otherbutton` will only trigger once for each click of `#mybutton`?

**EDIT**

Aha! I've just realised this is due to fancybox (where the buttons live).

The buttons are clicked from fancybox popop, which is also triggered to open every time before the buttons are clicked.

```
$('#planApp-link').fancybox().trigger('click');
```

I'm still not sure how to prevent this from happenning.

Comment: I don't think the issue you are having is related to the code you posted. Can you post more?

Comment: I think you are wrong - youll be clicking it  - and each time it will trigger it

Comment: Is there any other code within your event handler that you omitted?  It sounds like you're binding the `$('#otherbutton')` click event within the `$('#mybutton')` click handler.

Comment: Does the function download anything via ajax that could contain this script again, registering the event handlers multiple times?

Comment: You're right guys, it's to do with me calling fancybox (the buttons are inside the fancybox modal popup). See my edits above. Thanks.

Comment: Could you post some more of your code. Your initial posting contains example code and your edit contains actual app code and it's hard to get what goes where. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

instead of using trigger("click") u can use

$('#otherbutton').click();

this function it ll trigger the click function

```
     $(".clas1").on("click",function(){
         $(".clas2").click();
     });
     $(".clas2").on("click",function(){
      alert("div2");
     });
```

.

Comment: `.click()` and `.trigger('click')` are essentially the same